# Java app to get time from local machine time

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, using

I am developing a java system that will keep track of a certain company's fixed assets, calculate the depreciating value using the straight line accounting method so the depreciating value will always be constant. after calculating all this it should divide the figure by 12 to get a monthly depreciating value and then alert the user (finance) of the depreciating after every financial year. how can I make the java based app get the time from the local machine to trigger these alerts.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the current time on a machine?

Comment: Yes that exactly what I am asking and how can I make it give me those alerts.

Answer (score -1):

First set the financial year of your app to, for instance, (31/03/2015) and then compare with the current date from your local machine. Check out the code for clarity:

```
    if(getCurrentDate().equals((31/03/2015))||getCurrentDate().after((31/03/2015))){
          //then do something here
}
```

And here is the method to get current date:

```
public static java.util.Date getCurrentDate() {
        int month = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        calender.set(year, month, day);
        return calender.getTime();
    }
```